# local change in node modules file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to make some changes in one of my node module package. But the problem is that if I am changing any file inside node modules folder then the changes won't be available to the other developers as it won't be checked in. Others will install it via package.json.
Is there any way I can include the file in my application instead of node modules and will it be a good approach?

Kindly suggest if there is any other alternative.

Comment: One good way to achieve this is to fork the npm package on github and add your changed version as a dependency. [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

You have three options

1. Send a PR to the actual npm package, if the change is like a bug fix or enhancement that aligns with the actual packages goal.
2. Fork the package repo, and make changes and use it in your project as a dependency, in case you are adding changes that does not align with the goals of the actual package
3. move the package code into your source code, and use it as source code rather than a package from npm

Comment: My change is very minor. What if I need the latest code from the repository itself without overriding my small change. Or can i explicitly override one method from my local code. How can i check if that method is exposed for changes?

Comment: If you always want the latest from the repository with your changes, then the only option is to submit a pull request to the repository to add your changes into the actual package, so that it is available in future releases and to all customers

Answer (score 1):

you can make a fork of the project, then inside your package.json add the dependency as

```
"package-name": "<your username>/<your repo name/probably same as package-name>#<branch>",
```

also you can install it using yarn/npm

`npm install --save username/repo#branch-name-or-commit-or-tag`

as show this [link](https://medium.com/@jonchurch/use-github-branch-as-dependency-in-package-json-5eb609c81f1a)

this is all, run yarn o npm install and you'll get your changes, please make a PR to the original author and when this will be accepted you can return